# citing references in a rmd file & error in pandoc-citeproc.exe

Tags: r, build, package, knitr, bibliography

This is my first time that I want to use citations in my rmd file and I don't know how can I do it exactly. I converted my rmd file to pdf document, but I have problem in generating reference and bibliography. I get this error while knitting:

> pandoc-citeproc.exe: Could not find bibliography.bib pandoc.exe: Error
>   running filter pandoc-citeproc Filter returned error status 1 Error:
>   pandoc document conversion failed with error 83

This is my yaml context:

> ```
> >     title: "Context"
> >     author: "Minoo"
> >     date: "2017/06/06"
> >     output: 
> >       pdf_document:
> >         toc: true
> >         toc_depth: 3
> >     bibliography: bibliography.bib
> >     vignette: >
> >       %\VignetteIndexEntry{Context}
> >       %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
> >       %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}
> ```

and I have listed my citations like this in the last part of my rmd file:

```
@article{@Csardi2006, Csardi G, Nepusz T: The igraph software package for complex network research, InterJournal, Complex Systems 1695. 2006. http://igraph.org}
@article{@Butts2015, Butts C (2015). network: Classes for Relational Data. The Statnet Project (http://statnet.org). R package version 1.13.0, http://CRAN.R-project.org/package=network.}
@article{@Butts2008, Butts C (2008). “network: a Package for Managing Relational Data in R.” Journal of Statistical Software, 24(2). http://www.jstatsoft.org/v24/i02/paper.}
```

I either cite them in my contexts as [@Csardi2006]. 
Any idea to solve this problem? 
More specifically,how can I cite in a rmd file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you need either to place a bibliography.bib file into your working directory or list your bibliography into the head, e.g. for bibliography:

Write a bibliography.bib file manually in editor or with a program like [JabRef](http://www.jabref.org/). There are also ways to autogenerate with e.g. [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/):

```
% Encoding: UTF-8
    @article{csardi2006,
      author  = {G, Csardi and T, Nepusz},
      title   = {The igraph software package for complex network research},
      journal = {InterJournal, Complex Systems},
      year    = {2006},
      url     = {http://igraph.org},
    }
    @article{...}
    @article{...}
```

Save it into your working directory as "bibliography.bib".

The YAML metadata with bibliography:

```
---
title: "Context"
author: "Minoo"
date: "June 13, 2017"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
bibliography: bibliography.bib
---
```

Or YAML metadata with inclusion of references, e.g. for quick papers:

```
---
title: "Context"
author: "Minoo"
date: "June 13, 2017"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
references:
- id: csardi2006
  author:
  - family: Csardi
    given: G.
  - family: Nepusz
    given: T.
  publisher: InterJournal, Complex Systems
  title: The igraph software package for complex network research
  type: article-journal
  issued:
    year: 2006
---
```

Text section of RMD:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Text

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet [@csardi2006], consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam

## Biblio
````

Comment: Thanks for your response, but how should be the format of  bibliography.bib file and how can I write it? Should it be written in a script

Comment: @minoo I've extended my answer. I think your citations might be in a different format, you can compare them in an editor.

Comment: I am trying to do what you instruct, and one more question is that: you have written one of the references in the yaml and for more references do I have write the min the yaml too? if yes how?

Comment: In the bibliography method you just point at the *.bib file in the YAML where you put all your citations (I've corrected that now above..).

Comment: thank you for your compelete answer. I could generate the references.