# Equations and references lost when knitting RMarkdown document as Word

Tags: r, latex, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

(I'm not sure if this question is better suited to the LaTeX forum. I have posted it here because I suspect the problem is more about `knitr` and RMarkdown than LaTeX.)

I have the following RMarkdown document in RStudio:

```
 ---
 title: 'Capricious Behavior In Markdown: A Case Study'
 header-includes:
 - \usepackage{natbib}
 - \setcitestyle{square,numbers,super}
 output:
  word_document: default
  pdf_document:
    citation_package: natbib
  html_document: default
bibliography: refs.bib
---
Here's an equation with a citation\citep{aune}:

\begin{align}
5 &= 5
\end{align}
```

which produces the desired result when knitted as PDF:

[image]

but mysteriously loses both the equation and the reference when knitted as Word:

[image]

How do I produce a Word document that looks like the PDF?

Comment: This post discusses tweaking word output to different styles. May be worth checking out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671868/knitr-rmarkdown-docx-tables

Answer (score 0):

According to [rdabbler](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/103) I accomplished equations in Word using this code:

```
$$
\begin{array}{c}
5 = 5 
\end{array}
$$
```

Unfortunately equation numbering has beaten me, perhaps you can live with this issue.

As I rather used the [pandoc native citation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44520400/6574038) references they are even working with Word, but the style seems to be different to yours with the superscript numbers.