# RMarkdown Knitr + Natbib References Display (?)

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown

I am using `RMarkdown` and `Knitr` to compile a PDF document. I'm using Natbib and a `library.bib` file generated with Mendeley in order to make use of references using citation keys such as `{Author2017}`. It normally displays the references like this in the PDF:

> "Here is something I am saying in the text (Author, 2017)."

Now it looks like this:

> "Here is something I am saying in the text (?)."

As far as I understand this can be for one of two reasons:

1. Duplicate citation keys in the .bib file I use
2. I entered the wrong citation key somewhere in the document

I have already checked for duplicate citation keys in the `.bib` file. There aren't any. I assume I have entered the wrong citation key somewhere in the `.rmd` file. How do I find that wrong citation key?

Comment: Without reproducible code or some content (.bib file), it is hard to help you.

Comment: Can you post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)? Minimal `.rmd` code and the contents of `library.bib` to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't get your "2. ...*somewhere* in the document" - the wrong key  should be exactly there where the "?" appears?! - Anyway, I recommend the [rmarkdown native citation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44520400/6574038).

Comment: Look in the log file for more details about the error.  To get the log file, you may need to add `keep_tex: TRUE` to the YAML header, and process the resulting `.tex` file separately.  Then (in RStudio) you'll see the log by clicking on `View log` in the `Compile PDF` output tab.  It may also show up in `Issues` in the same output tab.

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you for your help! This question can be closed.